# C# bool expression evaluation order

Tags: c#, evaluation, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [== Operator and operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677264/-operator-and-operands)
>
> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any difference between if(a==5) or if(5==a) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797162/is-there-any-difference-between-ifa5-or-if5a-in-c)
>   [== Operator and operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677264/-operator-and-operands)

Ok, this may be stupid question, but searching in google (cant seem to ACTUALLY search for an exact phrase even with quotes)

What if any difference is there between

`if(false == <somecondition>){`

and

`if(<somecondition> == false){`

in C#? I am familiar with c#'s expression evalution, and understand how the order would make sense if you were doing something like:

`if(AccountIsInvalid || AccountIsUnregistered)`

I dont need a huge lesson, but would like to understand why some people prefer to do things with `false==....` route.

Comment: Dup of many... looking now...

Comment: Of course, use `if(!<somecondition>)` and it becomes a non-issue ;-p

Comment: One duplicate here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797162/is-there-any-difference-between-ifa5-or-if5a-in-c-closed

Comment: Another - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677264/operator-and-operands - which seems to be the "master" question

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I never compare anything to false or true.

I would go with:

```
if (!somecondition)
```

or:

```
if (somecondition)
```

Answer (score 3):

In C there would have been, perhaps, some reason to do this as you could easily make a mistake and use the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator, but in C# it shouldn't make any difference -- you'll get a compile warning if you use the assignment operator.  If the assignment were a different type (say int), it would result in an error, since the result wouldn't be a legal expression for the if statement.

I would prefer it to be

```
if (!<somecondition>)
{
  ...
}
```

rather than a comparison to false (or true, for that matter).

Comment: It is a warning, not an error: `bool b; if (b = true) { Console.WriteLine("abc"); }`

Comment: @Marc -- thanks for the clarification.  That's is certainly true in the case of a bool variable.  I hadn't considered that.  I guess I'm just too used to seeing it in the context of some other value type -- which would be an error.

Comment: Ah, fair enough ;-p Indeed, Cs tendency to treat anything non-zero as true is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Before performing any optimizations or short-circuits, the compiler needs to resolve `<somecondition>` to `true` or `false` value, thus there is no  reason why the compiler would evaluate the expressions `<somecondition> == false` and `false == <somecondition>` any differently.

This must surely be an issue of style, and style only.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't matter in C# like it does in c/c++ because conditions must evaluate to a boolean.

Comment: Not *quite* true... they must have an implicit conversion to boolean, or a true function. Note also that the result of assignment is still bool, and works...

Comment: Consider: `bool b; if (b = true) { Console.WriteLine("abc"); }`

Comment: true enough, I should have said doesn't matter "as much as it does..." because you cant accidentally do the following in C#

int i;
if( i = 0 ) {...}