# iPhone SDK: Please explain why "nil ==" is different than "== nil"

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, null

I have been programming iPhone SDK for around 6 months but am a bit confused about a couple of things...one of which I am asking here:

Why are the following considered different?

```
if (varOrObject == nil)
{

}
```

vs

```
if (nil == varOrObject)
{

}
```

Coming from a perl background this is confusing to me...

Can someone please explain why one of the two (the second) would be true whereas the first would not if the two routines are placed one after the other within code.  `varOrObject` would not have changed between the two `if` statements.

There is no specific code this is happening in, just that I have read in a lot of places that the two statements are different, but not why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [== Operator and operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677264/operator-and-operands)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797162/is-there-any-difference-between-ifa5-or-if5a-in-c for more explanations

Comment: "Considered different"? What made you think that they are "considered different"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the same. What you have read is probably talking about if you mistakenly write `==` as `=`, the former will assign the value to the variable and the `if` condition will be false, while the latter would be a compile time error:

```
if (variable = nil) // assigns nil to variable, not an error.

if (nil = variable) // compile time error
```

The latter gives you the chance to correct the mistake at compile time.

Comment: GCC 4.2 catches this at compile time with a warning.

Answer (score 4):

They might be different if you are using Objective-C++ and you were overriding the '==' operator for the object.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same, it is just a style difference. One would never be true if the other is false.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a recommendation that you use the latter, it's because the second is easier to catch if you accidentally type `=`. otherwise, they are identical and your book is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

They can only be different if the "==" - Operator is overloaded.
Let's say someone redefines "==" for a list, so that the content of two lists is checked rather than the memory adress (like "equals() in Java). Now the same person could theoretically define that "emptyList == NULL".

Now (emptyList==NULL) would be true but (NULL==emptyList) would still be false.